# Continuous-time Markov process - need help with flux and discrete-time equivalent

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I have a continuous-time markov process and I need to calculate the following:

- transition frequencies matrix (aka intensity matrix)
- transition probabilities
- all parameters which define permanence times in states
- the transition frequencies diagram
- the balance equations for the probability flux while in transient
- the markov discrete-time chain stochastically undistinguishable

Here's what I did:

- I wrote the matrix (first point) since it's an easy one.
- $$P(X(1)=j|X(0)=i) = \frac{q_{i,j}}{v_i}$$
- I think the parameters is here referring are the $\pi_i$ stationary probabilities since Permanence_time = $$\pi_i*h$$ where h is the time interval
- this should be the graphical representation with nodes and arcs from the first point's matrix, and I did this without problems
- I don't know what this point is referring to
- Idem, I don't know what does that mean

Can someone shed a bit of light on the last two points? I don't want the exercise done without trying, but I don't know how to proceed